# Safe PHP JSON logging

Tags: php, json

I am using JSON as a data store and over time I foresee that several parties might be wanting to write to my JSON file like a chat log within a short space of time.

```
<?php
$foo = json_decode(file_get_contents("foo.json"), true);
if (! is_array($foo["bar"])) { $foo["bar"] = array(); }
array_push($foo["bar"], array("time" => time(), "who" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], msg => $_GET['m']));
file_put_contents("foo.json", json_encode($foo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
?>
```

So the above code works, but I am worried what happens if the file is read before it's written out, or some case where they are writing out at the same time, leading to some data loss?

What's a better or safer design, preferably using flat file storage (i.e. not databases)?

As for a bonus I really don't want to return to my client who made the request this that were was some "lock". Ideally the request is made to wait until it's safe to return.

Comment: Instead of locking, you could use atomic operations that don't need locking. Standard JSON is not a good fit for this, as the whole file would needs to be read and decoded, before the data is modified and written back to disk. But you could just write each new set of data to a single line, and fwrite is meant to be atomic for writes that are smaller than the HD block size.

Comment: @Danack I wonder if http://jsonlines.org/ qualifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `flock()` function for this. What it does is it locks the file for all processes except the current one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Basic usage:

```php
<?php

$fp = fopen('path/to/data.json', 'r+');

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) // locks the file
{
    // write to the file

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // remove the lock
}

fclose($fp);
```

`flock()` is blocking by default. That means a process is waiting until it gets permission to access the lock. Have a look at the docs on how to implement a nonblocking version.

Comment: In most circumstances having explicit locking is only useful to prevent duplicate modification of files. That's not a problem here, as the files are just being over-written, and so more simpler atomic operations can be used.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution that describes what you mean? You are right, the file gets overwritten, but the OP wants to store messages sent by the user that get *appended* to the json. How do you prevent a user B from overwriting changes made by user A if they both read the same data from the json file?

Comment: I misread the question - and I should remove my downvote. Please could you make a trivial change to your answer, as votes get locked apparently.

Answer (score 0):

How a bout you create individual JSON for each line so you do not need load Json every time. and you just append JSON to the file.
Each Joson will be in One line.

When you load it you will read each line in text file then convert it to Json within PHP.

The reason I recommend this way as we want to find other way to have better solution for file read and write using   //http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
    file_put_contents("foo.json", json_encode($foo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT). 
JSON is just a format for text. So I believe that It is a good solution to do.

To write

```
<?php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], msg => $_GET['m']));

$foo =  array("time" => time(), "who" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], msg => $_GET['m']);
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
file_put_contents("foo.json", json_encode($foo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX));
?>
```

As you mention it is a log, so you may not need to load to see it all the time.
So we will to focus on writing. It may seem long process to read. 
TO read

```
<?php 

$log_array = array();
$handle = @fopen("foo.json", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

        $foo = json_decode($buffer, true);
        $log_array[] = $foo;

    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

print_r($log_array);

?>
```